# Roblox: Data is Saving, But Fails when trying to load?

Tags: roblox

So what I've been trying is to Save a certain "Text" to the DataStore from a TextLabel, The Data Saves Successfully, But when trying to load it gives me just gives me a "Failed",  Any Help?

Here's a Quick Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-J6U8zmATk&feature=youtu.be

Script:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local IDStorage = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("IDStorage3")

elseif Player.Team.Name == "Intelligence Agency" then
            if Player:IsInGroup(7503826) or Player:GetRankInGroup(7465879) >= 251 then
                Rank.User.Text = "[REDACTED]"
                Rank.User.Back.Text = "[REDACTED]"
                Rank.Rank.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0.827451, 0, 0)
            
                     
                game.ReplicatedStorage.NewID.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, playerToID, AssignedID)
                    if player:IsInGroup(7465879) then
                        local success, err = pcall(function()
                            IDStorage:SetAsync(playerToID, AssignedID)
                        end)
                            
                        if success then
                            print("Data Assigned") -- Data Works and Saves
                        else
                            warn("Failed to Save")
                        end
                    end
                end)
                
                
                local ID = IDStorage:GetAsync(Player)

                if ID then
                    print(ID) 
                else
                    warn("Failed") -- Always Returns me this.
                    Rank.Rank.Text = "0"
                end
                
                    Rank.User.Text = "[REDACTED]"
                    Rank.User.Back.Text = "[REDACTED]"
                end
```

Comment: When you call `IDStorage:SetAsync(key, value)` what arguments are you using for the key?

Comment: The key is the Username, and the Value the ID (playerToID, AssignedID). I have a GUI which Fires the Server and sends the Target (playerToID) and an ID (example: 1234567890) to assign for the user (AssignedID) (Both from a TextBox), If I understood the Question correctly. `@Kylaaa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataStore:GetAsync(key)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/GlobalDataStore/GetAsync) function expects a string for the key. It looks like you're passing in a `Player` object and not the player's username, which you said was the key that you were storing the data in.

Try this swapping this line

```
local ID = IDStorage:GetAsync(Player)
```

for this instead :

```
local success, result = pcall(function()
    local key = Player.Name
    return IDStorage:GetAsync(key)
end
if success then
    print("Got Id : ", result)
    local ID = result
    if ID then
        -- do stuff with the result
    else
        -- looks like a new player with no saved data
    end
else
    warn("failed to get id with error :", result)
    -- do something to handle the error, like retry
end
```

Something to be careful about when saving data is that usernames can change. If I were to change my name, the next time I joined this game, all of my progress would be gone because the name doesn't match up with the saved key. That is why a [player's userId](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/UserId) tends to be the recommend key.

Comment: The script works and the player gets found, But apperantly it says I have no "ID", Even after my New Given ID was saved/given. Looking with the "DataStore Editor" Plugin, My ID is saved. But when printing it out it says `Got Id : nil`

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your earlier comment, you said you are using the player's username, not userid. I'll adjust my answer.